# How to test content of a WAR from a separate Maven module using Arquillian

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I have found bits and pieces of knowledge around the web, but haven't been able to put it together to solve this specific case. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24580572/378606) seems a pretty good start, but it deals specifically with an EAR dependency.

My (simplified) maven project structure is as follows:

```
parent
 |__domain     (a jar)
 |__domain-it  (integration tests for the domain module)
 |__web        (a war; depends on domain)
 |__web-it     (integration tests for the web module)
```

I'm looking for a solution to the following:

1. I want to have Arquillian integration tests which test the code contained by the `web` module.
2. These tests will be contained in a separate `web-it` module.
3. Since the `web` module depends on the `domain` module, the `web-it` integration tests will also need to have the code from the `domain` module on the classpath.
4. Both `domain` and `web` have dependencies on some third party libraries, such as
   `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3` which will also be needed on the test classpath.
5. The tests need to run both via Maven on the command line and directly within Eclipse via junit.

I am running on Glassfish 3.1.2.

Any help would be appreciated. It's weird to me that there is no specific Arquillian documentation for this scenario, since I imagine it's a pretty common one. Perhaps I am missing something fundamental?

Here is some of what I have tried so far:

1. Make `web-it` depend on `web` by adding the following to `web-it/pom.xml` as follows:

   ```
   <dependency>  
       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
       <artifactId>web</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
       <type>war</type>
   </dependency>
   ```

   But this won't include any classes from `web` on the test classpath
2. Make `web-it` depend on the classes of `web` by configuring the war plugin of `web` to [produce an attached classes jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090564/378606). In `web/pom.xml`:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

   In `web-it/pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>  
       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
       <artifactId>web</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
       <classifier>classes</classifier>
   </dependency>
   ```

   This includes the classes from `web` on the test classpath, but none of the transitive dependencies (such as `commons-lang3`).

I've also considered, but not yet tried:

1. Using the [Maven Warpath plugin](http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin/), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770148/378606). There seem to be some issues when this is used with m2e/eclipse though, and I want to be able to run my integration tests from eclipse.
2. Using the [MavenImporter ShrinkWrap Resolver](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/README.asciidoc#maven-importer) somehow to just create an Arquillian deployment based on the project pom. I'm not sure how this will go running in eclipse (ie outside of maven), but it also means I need to effectively deploy the entire WAR, rather than just a subset of it - a feature of Arquillian that I like and would like to be able to preserve.

Comment: What version of maven-war-plugin do you use? `attachClasses` is available since 2.1-alpha-2